# CUDA thread execution in moving data in shared memoty

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have the following function:

**code example 1:**

```
__global__ void func(const int *input, int N){

  extern __shared__int buffer[];
  int temp = 0;

  for(int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < N; i += blockDim.x*gridDim.x; ){
     temp += input[i];
  }

  buffer[threadIdx.x] = temp;
  __syncthreads();

}
```

It is a part of a parallel reduction function. As far I understand it copies from global to shared memory.

I have tried to understand it by a simple example. For example I have a 1D array of size 20
elements (N=20). I imagine the execution as follows. Correct me If I am wrong. For 5 blocks of 4 threads each.

**Execution for all threads of the first block:**

```
blockIdx.x=0
threadIdx.x=0
for(i=0; i<18; i+= 4*5){ temp= in[0] /i wrote the sums intuitively/}        
buffer[threadIdx.x] = temp

blockIdx.x=0
threadIdx.x=1
for(i=1; i<18; i+= 4*5){ temp= in[1] /i wrote the sums intuitively/}
buffer[threadIdx.x] = temp

blockIdx.x=0
threadIdx.x=2
for(i=2; i<18; i+= 4*5){ temp= in[2] /i wrote the sums intuitively/}
buffer[threadIdx.x] = temp

blockIdx.x=0
threadIdx.x=3
for(i=3; i<18; i+= 4*5){ temp= in[3] /i wrote the sums intuitively/}
buffer[threadIdx.x] = temp
```

**Execution for all threads of the second block:**

```
blockIdx.x=1
threadIdx.x=0
for(i=1*4; i<18; i+= 4*5){ temp= in[4] /i wrote the sums intuitively/}
buffer[threadIdx.x] = temp

blockIdx.x=1
threadIdx.x=1
for(i=1*4+1; i<18; i+= 4*5){ temp = in[5] /i wrote the sums intuitively/}
buffer[threadIdx.x] = temp

blockIdx.x=1
threadIdx.x=2
for(i=1*4+2; i<18; i+= 4*5){ temp = in[6] /i wrote the sums intuitively/}
buffer[threadIdx.x] = temp

blockIdx.x=1
threadIdx.x=3
for(i=1*4+3; i<18; i+= 4*5){ temp = in[7] /i wrote the sums intuitively/}
buffer[threadIdx.x] = temp
```

**e.t.c.**

Why do we have a for loop instead of just writing:

**code example 2:**

```
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
buffer[threadIdx.x] = input[i];
```

Can someone give an intuitive example or explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main function, the elements with index greater than `blockDim.x*(gridDim.x-1)+(blockDim.x-1)` will be considered into calculation while in the method you've provided it doesn't happen.

Suppose you have `N=1024`, and you invoke your function with a grid having 8 blocks each of them with 32 threads. In your main function, thread `i` will collect and add up data belonging to `*input` at elements  `i`, `i+8*32`,`i+2*(8*32)`, `i+3*(8*32)`. On the other hand, your code collects data only at element `i`. In other words, it adds up only `32*8` first elements of `*input` and ignores `1024-32*8` rest.

**In more detail:**

code exmaple 1 works like this:

```
blockIdx.x=0
threadIdx.x=0
for ( i = 0; i < 1024; i += 32*8 )
    temp += input[i]; // temp= input[0]+input[256]+input[512]+input[768]
buffer[0] = temp; //=input[0]+input[256]+input[512]+input[768]

blockIdx.x=0
threadIdx.x=1
for ( i = 1; i < 1024; i += 32*8 )
    temp += input[i]; // temp= input[1]+input[257]+input[513]+input[769]
buffer[1] = temp; //=input[1]+input[257]+input[513]+input[769]

blockIdx.x=0
threadIdx.x=2
for ( i = 2; i < 1024; i += 32*8 )
    temp += input[i]; // temp= input[2]+input[258]+input[514]+input[770]
buffer[2] = temp; //=input[2]+input[258]+input[514]+input[770]
```

...

```
//last thread
blockIdx.x=7
threadIdx.x=31
for ( i = 7*32+31; i < 1024; i += 32*8 )
    temp += input[i]; // temp= input[255]+input[511]+input[767]+input[1023]
buffer[255] = temp; //=input[255]+input[511]+input[767]+input[1023]
```

code exmaple 2 works like this:

```
blockIdx.x=0
threadIdx.x=0
i = 0*32+0; //=0
buffer[0] = input[0];

blockIdx.x=0
threadIdx.x=1
i = 0*32+1; //=1
buffer[1] = input[1];
```

....

```
//last thread
blockIdx.x=7
threadIdx.x=31
i = 7*32+31; //=255
buffer[255] = input[255];
```

As you can see first code example, goes over all elements of `input` array but second code exmaple doesn't.

Comment: When you said `blockDim.x*(gridDim.x-1)+(blockDim.x-1)` in which part of your code do you refer? can you give more detailed explanations? (This part of the code is from a book).Do you mean that the example I gave is wrong or that the code is wrong?

Comment: In the main code, initialization of `i` for each thread at `for` loop is `blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x`. Maximum value for `blockDim.x` can be `gridDim.x-1` and maximum value for `threadIdx.x` can be `blockDim.x-1`. The last piece of code you've provided doesn't work correctly if `N` is greater than `blockDim.x*(gridDim.x-1)+(blockDim.x-1)`.

Comment: If you referring to the **code example 2** by saying the last piece of the code I think I understand you if you mean that we choose the `for` loop because of thread limitation. I just found a little strange to use a `for` loop that it has only one execution. In other words you means that the for loop is meaningful if we have a  a lot of elements? Only then it is executed more than once? Sorry for my ignorance I am new in cuda realm.

Comment: Yes I was referring to code exmaple 2 when I said last piece of code. Yes. If we have a lot of elements and we have limited number of blocks with limited size, using 'for' loop can be a solution.